# class in object element under asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, flash

I'm using in my web design asp.net the following code:

```
    <object id="ClockFrame01" class="System.Collections.ArrayList" width="70px" height="70px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" runat="server" data="http://www.worldtimeserver.com/clocks/wtsclock001.swf?color=808000&wtsid=US-CA" >
         <param name="movie" value="http://www.worldtimeserver.com/clocks/wtsclock001.swf?color=808000&wtsid=US-CA" />
         <param name="FlashVars" value="playerMode=embedded" />
         <param name=" wmode" value="permanent" />
         <param name="ShowDisplay" value="true"/>
</object>
```

to replace the old one which producing error:

```
<embed  src="http://www.worldtimeserver.com/clocks/wtsclock001.swf?color=808000&wtsid=US-CA" class="style_Clock" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" runat="server" />
```

But when debug my code; I'm missing clock from my web site!!!
It is obvious that I have a bad code but I don't know how to do it.

And the following class it works with same way:

```
class="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl"
```

Comment: Lefteri can you show us your page - I am not sure that I understand what is the error here. Euxaristo :) This is a simple embeded object, what is the issue with the asp.net actually ?

Comment: Trying change the embed/object tag to a literal and generating the embeded string code side. I say this cause depending on how deep the element id is it could cause issues. Also your embed tag doesnt have an id.

Comment: Aristos: Good day, my web site is www.panos-oliveoil.gr and there you'll see at the bottom few names, above each of those names I have an analogue clock sowing time around the world.

Comment: Aristos: At first I use the second code (that one with embed element) but that gives me an error telling me the embed is not supported; and of course the validation gives us errors.
Now I use the code with the object element and everything goes nice except that I lost the clocks from my page!!!!
Funny aaa.

Comment: Jonathan: Good day, I'm not sure I understand what you say; please give me sample code trying to answer in my question. And the classid at the element object is not an AND parameter but it is an OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the wrong typing in my code.
The right code is:

```
<object id="ClockFrame01" class="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl" width="70px" height="70px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.worldtimeserver.com/clocks/wtsclock001.swf?color=808000&wtsid=US-CA" >
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.worldtimeserver.com/clocks/wtsclock001.swf?color=808000&wtsid=US-CA" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="playerMode=embedded" />
    <param name=" wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="true"/>
</object>
```

The error was the

> runat="server"

The object MUST have NOT this instruction!!!

Also you need to make some changes: 
the

> &wtsid

needs to change in

```
&amp;wtsid
```